# Android ListView with CardView: Last Card not fully displayed when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-cardview

[image]

I have created a ListView to which I've added CardView.

As you can see in the image, when I start scrolling, the last Card in the ListView is not completely displayed. It scrolls up but it does not come above Android's navigation bar at the bottom. I've been testing on a HTC One M8.

Here is the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wanna_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@null"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the CardView that I inflate and set into the adapter of the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
    <!-- compat padding is required if using AppCompat -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/india"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/firstLine"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Tennis with Peter"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/secondLine"
                android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
                android:text="10 Oct at 7pm"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstLine" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="YES"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NO"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried my card view layout without wrapping it in a LinearLayout and it still does not work.

Is there a setting in the layout xml that will take care of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add margin in bottom in card view.

Comment: add some top and bottom margin to `listview`

Comment: Is this the standard way of doing it? Seems strange that Android is not able to recognise that its clipping part of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 android:layout_marginBotton=" "
```

add margin bottom should try once.

Answer (score 2):

So adding a margin to the bottom of listView worked, as below:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/wanna_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />
```

Am surprised this is the only way to get it to work though. I would have assumed the Android framework took care of these things.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `ListView` in a **Fragment** ? As far as I know, this is possible when you have used a **`Toolbar`** such as :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ...
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        ...
          >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then change the attribute to:

```
    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

Adding margin at the bottom of ListView is sort of a hack. I have given a probable cause for this. If this is the case, then you won't need to add the margin in ListView. There is always a reason behind the UI behavior. I hope this helps.